# MFC-C Code merge issue

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, mfc, merge

I am writing MFC-GUI on the top of C Code, after taking lib & include files from the c code i am getting redefinition error for many variable mentioned below-

```
error C2011: 'fd_set' : 'struct' type redefinition

error C2011: 'timeval' : 'struct' type redefinition

error C2011: 'hostent' : 'struct' type redefinition
error C2011: 'netent' : 'struct' type redefinition

error C2011: 'servent' : 'struct' type redefinition

error C2011: 'protoent' : 'struct' type redefinition
```

and many more....

it has nothing do with code as independently it is working fine so i need some help in merge configuration.
How i did-
I created one new MFC project + solution, added one dialog in it, build it- worked fine; Now i added one existing C project in above solution, configured MFC project for added C project. in configuration i have given all the required Lib & include path.
Now from MFC code i am trying to include C code file & it is giving me above said error.

Did i missed something or i added something wrongly ?

Please help me to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: File definitions are duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure to add `#pragma once` at the top of all your .h files.
2. Check for multiple inclusion of .h files.

   Eg. *if your `main.cpp` includes `head1.h` and `head2.h` and both the `head1.h` and `head2.h` includes a common header say `utils.h` , it can cause such redefinition issues.
   Check and null out such occurrences if any.*

Comment: Thanks a lot...yes it was the same issue..even i was also looking into the same area...but the key point here is- issue was in the c code & this c code is compiles independently but not when we tried with MFC.
Thanks again !!!!